# Does virtual/overridable property functionality in an EF storage context exist the same way in a domain layer?

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

This is a hard question to frame/ask. I'm asking about efficiency in memory use and execution. The application is using ASP.NET MVC. I included in the title `virtual` for C# and `overridable` for VB because I don't think the language makes a difference for this question.

The code has a `UI/controller/domain/storage` layered architecture. In the storage layer the following model design is used:

```
StorageParent

StorageChild
  public virtual StorageParent StorageParent { get; set; }
    --OR---
  Public Overridable Property StorageParent As StorageParent

StorageGrandchild
  public virtual StorageChild StorageChild { get; set; }
    --OR---
  Public Overridable Property StorageChild As StorageChild
```

This allows the StorageGrandchild to access the StorageParent's ID by Grandchild.Child.Parent.ParentID .  But that is in the storage layer.

Access to all the ID's in the hierarchy is required in the Controller/UI layer.  But I'm a little unsure about the proper way to provide a path to the Parent from the Grandchild using the Domain layer.

If I declare a Property in the Domain like below, does that create just a reference to the Parent, or does it actually reserve additional memory with the accompanying necessary time to transfer data in the `Domain layer Child record` for an entire Parent record, and the same for the Grandchild?  In which case the `virtual/overridable` keywords wouldn't be applicable here, yes?

```
Parent

Child
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    --OR---
  Public Overridable Property Parent As Parent

Grandchild
  public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
    --OR---
  Public Overridable Property Child As Child
```

My question is triggered because I thought the `virtual/overridable` keywords only function to provide navigation in the EF context and that this navigation functionality wouldn't exist in a model defined outside of the EF context such as in Domain layer code.

I only need access to the ParentID, not the whole record. Should I define distinct ID records as Integers in the Domain records as below:

```
Parent

Child
  ParentID

Grandchild
  ChildID
  ParentID
```

Or can I use a property defined as the Parent without using additional memory and wasting execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it actually reserve additional memory

In a sense, yes. A reference itself (as compiled code) doesn't take much memory. But for `Grandchild.Child.Parent.ID` to work both `Child` and `Parent` must be loaded, which takes more memory than a `Grandchild` with two ID values. Side note: I think `Grandchild.Child.Parent.ParentID` was a typo and should have been `Grandchild.Child.Parent.ID`. If so, `Grandchild.Child.ParentID` would have the same effect.

> In which case the virtual/overridable keywords wouldn't be applicable here

The `virtual` keyword serves to enable lazy loading. It triggers EF to materialize entities as lazy-loading proxy objects that override the `virtual` navigation properties. Which says it all: lazy loading is a data access layer concept. You may want to make properties `virtual` in a domain layer, but it can't be for *that* purpose.

> Should I define distinct ID records as Integers in the Domain records

In a domain layer you don't want to work with ID values, so that's easy: no. It's up to you whether you want `GrandChild` to have a redundant reference to its `Child`'s `Parent`. Rule of the thumb: avoid redundancy.

So in the end, from a domain perspective, yes, load the references and take the memory overhead for granted.

However, it's more interesting to ask yourself the question if the memory (and time!) consuming operation of duplicating entity objects into domain objects is really worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for a solid focused answer. WRT parentID, I took to naming ID's according to model for clarity elsewhere in the code. Perhaps that's a standards violation?  You're right, I need to think through how to get those things I need in the domain with minimal reads accepting there will always be what sometimes seems to be unnecessary reads.